# Short text classification vs short-text classification

Tags: hyphens

I wonder which form is correct amongst *short text classification* vs *short-text classification*.

---

I have encountered both versions:

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/:

> LibShortText is an open source tool for **short-text classification** and analysis

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10167494598594398915&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22:

> Transductive learning for **short-text classification** problems using latent semantic indexing

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2551566654157015825&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22:

> **Short text classification** in Twitter to improve information filtering

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13964840928079120889&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22:

> **Short text classification** improved by learning multi-granularity topics

Comment: It looks like your contexts are referring to the classification of short texts, so ***short text*** is a "noun adjunct" being used adjectivally to identify a very specific type of classification. That's as opposed to the more general concept of *text classification*. Thus, for example, a *short text classification guide* might be a short guide to text classification. In principle you could use a hyphen to join *short-text* if you want to unambiguously convey the former meaning, or *text-classification* for the latter, but most writers don't do either (context invariably suffices).

Comment: There is no "correct" or "incorrect" here, merely clarity vs. ambiguity. The hyphen is disambiguation: classification of short texts rather than short classification of texts.   From the link: "It can handle the classification of, for example, titles, questions, sentences, and short messages."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two words are being taken together to describe a third word, or to narrow down the scope of the third word, the convention is that the two words immediately prior to the principle noun can be hyphenated.

For instance, for work I do, I describe children of an age to go to Primary school.

I use "*primary school-age children*".

In the original question, the use of the hyphen is more substantive.

Is the classification applying to short texts?

Is the phrase describing text classifications which are short?  (Perhaps the final label is short.  Perhaps the process is brief).

The hyphen can help remove the ambiguity.

*short-text classification* would be the classification of short texts.

*short text-classification* would be a brief process for,  or outcome of, a text-classification.